# Who is setting the modified flag on my files in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Over the course of the last few years I've been slowly growing my Emacs configuration, adding bits and pieces, add new modes etc. Around a year ago a problem started to occur regularly: some code is setting the modified bit on my buffers. It doesn't actually change anything, it just sets this flags. It is slightly annoying since each time I run `compile` or `save-some-buffers` I have to manually discard the changes in these buffers to reset the modified bit. How can I find the offending code?

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to phils, I expect that your modified-p flag is not set by `set-buffer-modified-p` but rather by actual changes to the buffer.  The reason this is possible is that text-properties are treated by Emacs as belonging to the content of the buffer, so changing them sets the modified-p flag, even tho in many cases the result is invisible and even if it is visible it is generally not perceived by the user as a *modification* (which users generally understand as something like "affects the file when I save the buffer").

So, most of the code that sets text-properties needs to be careful to reset the modified-p flag afterwards.  The best way to do that is usually by wrapping the code that sets the properties inside a `with-silent-modification`.

One way try to track down the culprit is by trying to undo the modification (e.g. with `C-/`), but of course, if the modification is not visible, undoing it won't be visible either.  So instead you may want to look at `C-h v buffer-undo-list RET` which is the internal data used to keep track of the modifications.  With luck, not only was the modified-p set but the undo-list as well, and that list will tell you what was changed.  For example, that list could look like `(nil (nil face nil 12345708 . 12345713))` which means that the change was to set the `face` property to a new value between positions 12345708 and 12345713 and that the old value of that property was `nil` (that's the 3rd `nil` in the above).  Sometimes looking at the affected positions with `M-: (goto-char 12345708) RET` is sufficient to figure out who's to blame.  Othertimes looking at `M-: (get-text-property 12345708 'face) RET`, which gives you the new value that was set, is more useful.

Comment: I agree completely -- I'll be very surprised if my answer actually shows the culprit. It seemed worth eliminating it as a possible cause, though; and I couldn't think of an obvious way to debug the alternative :)

Comment: @phils You'd be stepping out pretty far on a limb to disagree with a maintainer!  :)

Answer (score 3):

If something really is explicitly setting the buffer as modified without changing anything, then I guess it ought to be calling `set-buffer-modified-p`.

I was originally going to suggest `debug-on-entry` for `set-buffer-modified-p`, but a cursory test showed that was extremely disruptive in general, so here's a way you can indicate which buffers you are interested in:

```el
(defvar my-debug-set-buffer-modified-p-buffers nil)

(defadvice set-buffer-modified-p
  (before my-debug-set-buffer-modified-p-advice)
  (when (memq (current-buffer) my-debug-set-buffer-modified-p-buffers)
    (debug)))
(ad-activate 'set-buffer-modified-p)

(defun my-debug-set-buffer-modified-p (buffer)
  (interactive (list (current-buffer)))
  (if (memq buffer my-debug-set-buffer-modified-p-buffers)
      (progn (setq my-debug-set-buffer-modified-p-buffers
                   (delq buffer my-debug-set-buffer-modified-p-buffers))
             (message "Disabled for %s" buffer))
    (add-to-list 'my-debug-set-buffer-modified-p-buffers buffer)
    (message "Enabled for %s" buffer)))
```